# Call a C preprocessor macro multiple times (through a variable)

Tags: c, assembly, macros

I'd like to clean up my assembly code and povide a way to call "NOP" multiple times through a macro:

```
#define NOP() asm(" nop")

#define NOP_N( N ) \
    NOP(); \
    NOP(); \
    .... call NOP() N times
```

I can't figure if this is possible in a macro.

Obviously, for performance reasons, I don't want something like this:

```
#define NOP_N( n ) { register int i; for(i=0;i<n;i++) asm(" nop"); }
```

Which defeats the purpose of NOP:

```
L17:                                    ; NOP_N(3);
        nop
        addi      1,r0                  ; Unsigned
        cmpi      3,r0
        blo       L17
```

The code is in C and assembly, so no C++ can be involved in here. Also, the compiler is fairly old and doesn't support variadic macros...

Comment: how do you write it as macro for `N`, `call NOP() N times`,  N has to be know at coding time

Comment: @Mogria: Well if xgbi can use C++, then this could be done fairly simply via template metaprogramming, and no preprocessor trickery would be necessary at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11532883/946850

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/319328/946850

Comment: The code is in C and assembly, so no C++ can be involved in here. Also, the compiler is fairly old and doesn't support variadic macros...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think a solution for unbounded `N` is possible. For bounded `N` you could do something along the following lines:

```
#define REPEAT_0(WHAT)
#define REPEAT_1(WHAT) WHAT REPEAT_0(WHAT)
#define REPEAT_2(WHAT) WHAT REPEAT_1(WHAT)
#define REPEAT_3(WHAT) WHAT REPEAT_2(WHAT)

#define NOP_N(N) REPEAT_##N(asm("nop");)
```

The first part can be autogenerated easily. The technique employed for the second part is sometimes called [token pasting](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Comment: That's the closest that I can foresee as possible without variadic macros.

Answer (score 2):

what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532975/1031417) and [Is the C preprocessor Turing complete?](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/Is-the-C-preprocessor-Turing-complete%3F):

```
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL1(EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL1(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL3(EVAL3(EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL3(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL5(EVAL5(EVAL5(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL5(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

**AND REPEAT_INDIRECT**

```
#define REPEAT(count, macro, ...) \
    WHEN(count) \
    ( \
        DEFER(REPEAT_INDIRECT) () \
        ( \
            DEC(count), macro, __VA_ARGS__ \
        ) \
        DEFER(macro) \
        ( \
            DEC(count), __VA_ARGS__ \
        ) \
    )
#define REPEAT_INDIRECT() REPEAT

//An example of using this macro
#define M(s, i, _) i
EVAL(REPEAT(8, M, ~)) // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

**AND FOREVER:**

```
#define FOREVER() \
    ? \
    DEFER(FOREVER_INDIRECT) () ()
#define FOREVER_INDIRECT() FOREVER
// Outputs question marks forever
EVAL(FOREVER())
```

Comment: Care to elaborate what this code does? Otherwise the link is great in a comment but does not qualify for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in the preprocessor (and have a C99 compliant compiler) you could use [P99_UNROLL](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for.html) from P99.

But you are completely underestimating the optimization that modern compilers are capable. As long as the bounds are compile time constants, a good compiler with optimization should just unroll the code for you. Look into the assembler to be sure (gcc has `-S` for that).

But you probably could help the compiler a bit by coding this "correctly":

```
#define NOP_N(N) for(register unsigned i=0; i < (N); i++) asm(" nop")
```

That is, have the loop counter local to the `for` and use an unsigned type such that there can't be theoretical issues with overflow.

Comment: The thing is that the compiler *is* old. I checked that using a for loop will actually initialize the integer and not unroll the loop.