# How to compare arrays and check if it's in correct order

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check if an array's values are in the correct order. For example if, I want to check if an array is in the order `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7} or even a different order such as{1,2,4,3,5,6,7}, {1,4,2,3,5,6,7}, (4,1,2,3,5,6,7},{1,2,3,5,4,6,7},{1,2,3,5,6,4,7},etc.

I had tried this and it didn't work:

```
int board[7]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
if(board[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7})
    return true;
```

Is there a way to apply this concept?

Comment: you want to check if the array is sorted, or do you want to check if the array is exactly equal to another array?

Comment: If it's actually C you're using and you want to use array literals, then maybe this answer suits you better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24153883/6486738

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal

Comment: FYI, one `'='` for assignment, two `'=='` for equality comparison.

Comment: Are you asking how to check if an array contains a permutation of the numbers from 1 to 7?

Comment: Perhaps if you edit the question to include examples that should pass, and examples that should fail, that will help clarify the question.

Comment: [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) will tell you if they contain the same elements regardless of order.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to go over the array. E.g.:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; ++i) {
    if (board[i] < board[i - 1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: my problem is that i dont only want to do this when it's in numerical order it could be any one of these {1,2,4,3,5,6,7}, {1,4,2,3,5,6,7}, (4,1,2,3,5,6,7},{1,2,3,5,4,6,7},{1,2,3,5,6,4,7}.etc

Comment: @DevenColeman please edit your question and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @DevenColeman Ok, then the duplicate target seems correct. Please read that and edit the question if your question is different.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're looking for [std::is_sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted):

```
return std::is_sorted(std::begin(board), std::end(board));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::equal` from standard library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int tab1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int tab2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    if( std::equal( std::begin(tab1), std::end(tab1), std::begin(tab2), std::end(tab2) ) )
    {
        std::cout << "tables are equal" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you use c++20, this code become cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int tab1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int tab2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    if(std::ranges::equal( tab1, tab2))
    {
        std::cout << "tables are equal" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```