# How to define variables with decrease numbers in name in C/C++ using macro?

Tags: c, macros

I have variables `a1, a2...a32`
so How do I define them using macro?

I tried

```
#define Name(i) a##i
for(int i=1; i<32;i++)
{
   Name(i) = 1;
}
```

but actually `Name(i)` gives me

```
 ai
```

instead of

```
a1 ... a32
```

ps:

I do know vector. But now the variable names are given, so I can't just write `array[i]=1`, I have to write `a1=1; ...; a32=1` etc, which makes me wanna use macro.

Comment: Use `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` and `BOOST_PP_SUB`. Still, what you've shown doesn't require decreasing numbers or 32 variables.

Comment: You can't do this with macros. Look at `std::vector`. **books:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You cannot combine macros and c code that way. For this to work you would have to write the loop using the macro language, but there's no such thing.

Comment: I can't use boost in my project. I do know vector. But now the variable names are given, so I can't just write `array[i]=1`, I have to write `a1=1; ... a32=1`...which makes me wanna use macro.

Comment: Well, `i` is what you pass to the macro. Think about when the preprocessor runs. Hint: not at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, actually it's possible to implement loops in C macros:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason in real world programming why you would be "given" variable names. But if you for reasons unknown must use those names, then put them in a union.

```
typedef struct
{
  int a1;
  int a2;

  ...

  int a32;
} variables;

typedef union
{
  variables var;
  int array [32];
} my_union;


my_union mu;

for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
{
  mu.array[i] = ...;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is better. And when you are working in a complex project with hundreds of guys and many systems, you would know what I am saying.

Comment: @Lynton No, if you are working in such a system and you get handed something with fundamentally wrong program design, you tell them that the program needs to rewritten. Or the project will rapidly code rot.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array-like container (`std::array` or `std::vector`):

```
std::array<Type, 32> a;
```

and the loop trough it with:

```
for (auto element : a) { ... }
```

or use any standard algorithm.

When you have a bunch of numbered variables, that's usually a code smell for something that should be an array.

Comment: I do know vector. But now the variable names are given, so I can't just write `array[i]=1`, I have to write `a1=1; ... a32=1`...which makes me wanna use macro.