# Loop unrolling in Metal kernels

Tags: ios, kernel, metal, loop-unrolling

I need to force the Metal compiler to unroll a loop in my kernel compute function. So far I've tried to put `#pragma unroll(num_times)` before a `for` loop, but the compiler ignores that statement.

It seems that the compiler doesn't unroll the loops automatically — I compared execution times for 1) a code with `for` loop 2) the same code but with hand-unrolled loop. The hand-unrolled version was 3 times faster.

E.g.: I want to go from this:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    do_stuff();
}
```

to this:

```
do_stuff();
do_stuff();
do_stuff();
```

Is there even something like loop unrolling in the Metal C++ language? If yes, how can I possibly let the compiler know I want to unroll a loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Metal is a subset C++11, and you can try using template metaprogramming to unroll loops. The following compiled in metal, though I don't have time to properly test it:

```
template <unsigned N> struct unroll {

    template<class F>
    static void call(F f) {
        f();
        unroll<N-1>::call(f);
    }
};

template <> struct unroll<0u> {

    template<class F>
    static void call(F f) {}
};

kernel void test() {

    unroll<3>::call(do_stuff);

}
```

Please let me know if it works! You'll probably have to add some arguments to `call` to pass arguments to `do_stuff`.

See also: [Self-unrolling macro loop in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231743/self-unrolling-macro-loop-in-c-c)