# How to avoid code bloat when using pthreads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, c-preprocessor

When writing threaded code in C, I first have to create some `struct` which includes all the arguments and a wrapper function. This leads to lots of code bloat and is not easy to read. See:

```
struct some_function_args {
  int arg1;
  int arg2;
  int arg3;
};

void some_function_wrapper(struct some_function_args* args) {
  some_function(args->arg1, args->arg2, args->arg3);
}

int main() {
  struct my_args;
  my_args.arg1 = 1;
  my_args.arg2 = 2;
  my_args.arg3 = 3;

  pthread_create(..., some_function_wrapper, &my_args);
  pthread_join(...);
}
```

Is there some kind of macro or library (maybe using `varargs`) which automatically creates the needed structs and wrapper functions for me, like this? Or is this not possible at all in C?

```
int main() {
  MY_THREAD thread = IN_THREAD {
    some_function(1, 2, 3);
  }

  JOIN_THREAD(thread);
}
```

Comment: Note that `some_function_wrapper` should take a `void*` and explicitly cast it to `struct some_function_args*`. Otherwise it'll get called with the wrong prototype, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Newer C-standards (C99) have compound initializers: `struct  my_args = {.arg1 = 1, .arg2 = 2, .arg3 = 3};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **EDIT:** I released some code. See [threadify.h](https://github.com/iblue/threadify.h).

With the following macros you can do things like this:

```
char a = 'A';
int  b = 23;
char[] c = "Example";


pthread_t thread;

// THREAD3 because it takes 3 arguments of variable type.
THREAD3(thread, a, b, c, {
  printf("test: %c %d %s\n", a, b, c);
});

JOIN(thread);
```

It's possible in GCC, because GCC has two non-standard extensions:

- nested functions
- The `typeof()` operator

There are some drawbacks in this huge mess of macros:

- You cannot pass rvalues (because it's not possible to create pointers to them)
- You need to use the appropriate `THREAD0`, `THREAD1`, ... macro depending on the number of arguments (not sure if it's possible to work around this using variadic macros).

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <pthread.h>

  // Nested definition to work around preprocessor prescan
  #define __CAT(arg1, arg2) arg1 ## arg2
  #define CAT(arg1, arg2) __CAT(arg1, arg2)

  // Use the current line number to create a unique name for objects
  #define NAME(arg1) CAT(arg1, __LINE__)

  // Creates a thread without any arguments
  #define THREAD0(thread, code) \
  void NAME(__pthread_wrapper)(void) {\
    do {code;} while(0); \
  }; \
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*)NAME(__pthread_wrapper), NULL);

  // Creates a thread with one argument by creating a struct
  // and passing all values via this struct.
  #define THREAD1(thread, arg1, code) \
  typedef struct { \
    typeof(arg1)* NAME(__pthread_arg1); \
  } NAME(__pthread_struct); \
    void NAME(__pthread_wrapper)(NAME(__pthread_struct)* data) {\
    do {code;} while(0); \
  }; \
  NAME(__pthread_struct) NAME(__data); \
  NAME(__data).NAME(__pthread_arg1) = &arg1; \
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*)NAME(__pthread_wrapper), &NAME(__data));

  #define THREAD2(thread, arg1, arg2, code) \
  typedef struct { \
    typeof(arg1)* NAME(__pthread_arg1); \
    typeof(arg2)* NAME(__pthread_arg2); \
  } NAME(__pthread_struct); \
    void NAME(__pthread_wrapper)(NAME(__pthread_struct)* data) {\
    do {code;} while(0); \
  }; \
  NAME(__pthread_struct) NAME(__data); \
  NAME(__data).NAME(__pthread_arg1) = &arg1; \
  NAME(__data).NAME(__pthread_arg2) = &arg2; \
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*)NAME(__pthread_wrapper), &NAME(__data));

  #define THREAD3(thread, arg1, arg2, arg3, code) \
  typedef struct { \
    typeof(arg1)* NAME(__pthread_arg1); \
    typeof(arg2)* NAME(__pthread_arg2); \
    typeof(arg3)* NAME(__pthread_arg3); \
  } NAME(__pthread_struct); \
    void NAME(__pthread_wrapper)(NAME(__pthread_struct)* data) {\
    do {code;} while(0); \
  }; \
  NAME(__pthread_struct) NAME(__data); \
  NAME(__data).NAME(__pthread_arg1) = &arg1; \
  NAME(__data).NAME(__pthread_arg2) = &arg2; \
  NAME(__data).NAME(__pthread_arg3) = &arg3; \
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*)NAME(__pthread_wrapper), &NAME(__data));

  /* THREAD4, THREAD5, ... */

  #define JOIN(thread) pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  ```

Comment: Maybe you could isolate the parameters in a pair of parentheses like so : `THREAD(thread, (a, b, c), {...})` ? I'm no PP guru, but I've seen crazy stuff done in Boost and this looks basic enough.

Comment: Then I still need to iterate through them somehow to create the struct. Maybe I could build some `#for VAR in (a,b,c)` loop using the following technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10542793/773690

Comment: Boost PP will probably be of great use here. Also please have a look at [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330956/how-to-avoid-code-bloat-when-using-pthreads-in-c/28332447#comment45010969_28330956) about the function pointer. This way will probably work, but better standard-compliant than sorry.

Answer (score -1):

'When writing threaded code in C, I first have to create some struct which includes all the arguments and a wrapper function. This leads to lots of code bloat and is not easy to read'.   Sure.  That's what you pay for making your app, (assuming it's not stupid), either X times faster or X times easier to implement becasue it's easier described as independent functionality.   You want something for nothing?