# Check if an expression is an lvalue with the preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a macro which checks if an expression is a `lvalue` ([meaning I can do `&expression`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue)) using the C preprocessor?

*Example:* If there is some `int a;` and I call `IS_LVALUE(a)` it should evaluate to 1, while `IS_LVALUE(5)` should evaluate to 0, so I can do `#if IS_LVALUE(...) == 1`

Comment: Just curious, why do you need this?

Comment: I'm trying to create lamba expressions using preprocessor macros. When passing an argument, I need to know if it's an lvalue (Then I create a pointer) or not (then I just pass the value). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28332447/773690

Comment: Why not just use `C++11` lambdas?

Comment: @RPGillespie and ruin the fun ? **No**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Because the C preprocessor has no clue what an lvalue is, or any other C construct for that matter. That's the compiler's job.

Were you in C++ you could use a type trait, but in C I'm afraid you're out of luck.