# mocking: extracting arguments to a function to create another function with same signature

Tags: c++, c++11, types

I am mocking a class `A`. It has 15 virtual functions that i want to override and call passed lambdas from that.

Code is:

```
struct A {
   virtual int funcA(int , int) ;
   virtual void funcB(double) ;
   // ... more..
};
```

Mock Class:

```
struct MockA : public A {
    std::function<decltype(funcA)> lambdaA;
    virtual decltype(((A*)nullptr)->funcA()) funcA(/* How to get aruments*/) override {
        return lambdaA(/* How to forward the arguments. */);
    }
};
```

I can not understand how to get arguments and forward them to `lambdaA` ?

Comment: I don't think C++ allows extraction of method signatures.  You'll probably need to use preprocessor tricks instead.

Comment: ok. how to do that ?

Comment: You can create a method declaration helper macro, then use the `__COUNTER__` macro to create a series of macros that save the method definitions uniquely.  Then you can use the approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor) to recursively define the mock class methods.  Unless you have a lot of classes it's probably easier to just copy-paste to create your mock class.

Comment: You may replace `((A*)nullptr)->funcA()` by `std::declval<A>().funcA()`.

Comment: @MooseBoys i am sorry to say.. but rather than using that macro i would write simple program for the task.

Comment: You may do something with function traits (a little bit improved compared to Boost's ones), variadic templates and the indices trick. But even then, you would probably need some more work and indirection and it would still choke on overloaded function (not overwritten ones).