# Stringize loopcounter to reference members of C struct

Tags: c, struct, stringification

I have two structs that appears like:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

struct my_struct_2 {
int type;
int length; //will be 2 in this case
byte value1; //MSB
byte value2; //LSB
}

struct my_struct_4 {
int type;
int length; //will be 4 in this case
byte value1; //MSB
byte value2;
byte value3;
byte value4; //LSB
}
```

I want to loop through the "value" members in the struct based on "length" to concatenate the byte values into one number.  I am wondering if it is possible to use some sort of stringizing so that I can construct a for loop with a structure similar to this:

```
int value = 0;
for( int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
{
    value = value << 8;
    value = value & my_struct.value#i#;
}
```

I want to take advantage of the fact that the structs members are sequentially named.

I know that I can accomplish this task by using a pointer to the first value and incrementing the pointer.  I am trying to familiarize myself more with stringizing so please refrain from a pointer like solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not an array :`byte value[4];` and `value = value & my_struct.value[i];`

Comment: I guess as long as the struct stays this way casting might work as well: `int value = (int)(&my_struct_4_instance.value1);`

Comment: Yes, an array is the right way to do this.

Comment: The formatting of the structs cannot be modified, as they are from a 3rd party.  Is that what you're suggesting?  In any case, I could always use a pointer to the first value and address that pointer as an array from then on out.  But I really want to know if this can be accomplished using stringizing :)

Comment: "if this can be accomplished using stringizing" No, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to loop through struct fields by constructing names like that.  Once a C program has been compiled, any information about names is gone (ignoring information for the debugger); it's all offsets hard-coded into the machine code.

With some [C preprocessor abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor) you can get something *a bit like* looping on names, but it's not pretty and definitely not recommended unless you're just doing it for the challenge of doing it.