# Define multiple similar variables with C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Microcontroller has many pins, every defined like

```
const Leg PA29 { PIOA, BIT(29) };   // struct Pin is already taken
// ... about 120 more: 4 port x 32 pin
```

I wrote a simple `define` to make alias in shorter form

```
#define P(Port,PinN)  \
    const Leg P##Port##PinN { PIO##Port, BIT(PinN) }
```

Using it as

```
P(D,2);  //produces PD2 with { PIOD, BIT(2) }
```

Nice.
Now I need-wont call `P` 120+ times for 4 ports with 32 pins in each. I would like to see something like

```
FOR_EACH( X in A,B,C,D ) \
  FOR_EACH( i in 0..31 ) \
    P(X,i);
```

Please do not suggest TCL, python etc. to generate C++ code.
I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor#10542793), but it is to complicated to understand how to use it in my case.

**The main idea is to avoid 120 rows with copy-paste. All 120+ pins should be defined in about 10 lines.**

upd. How `BIT` is defined:

```
///@param n is value from 0 to number of bits in unsigned value
template<typename UnsignedIntegerT=unsigned>
constexpr UnsignedIntegerT BIT(UnsignedIntegerT n){ return 1<<n; }
```

#### upd2. Minimal example

```
///////////////////
// Vendor provides something like:
///////////////////

struct Pio
{
    unsigned reg1;
    unsigned reg2;
    unsigned reg3;
    //...
    unsigned regN;
};


// values not from datasheet but from lantern
#define PIOA  ((Pio*)0xAABB6789)
#define PIOB  ((Pio*)0xAABB2569)
#define PIOC  ((Pio*)0xAABB2566)
#define PIOD  ((Pio*)0xAABB2323)
//...



/////////////
// Kyb's code
/////////////

class Leg 
{
public:
    Pio *pio;
    unsigned pinN;
//methods...
};


///@param n is value from 0 to number of bits in unsigned value
template<typename UnsignedIntegerT=unsigned>
constexpr UnsignedIntegerT BIT(UnsignedIntegerT n){ return 1u<<n; }


//////////////
// Now need to define 120+ pins-legs

// like this
const Leg PA29 { PIOA, BIT(29) };

// or with shortener alias

/// Alias to shortly produce leg definition
/// Example: `P(A,2)` will define `PA2` with proper PIO and bit.
#define P(Port,PinN)  \
        const Leg P##Port##PinN { PIO##Port, BIT<unsigned>(PinN) }

//P(D,4);  //produces PD4
//P(C,3);
```

Comment: Your post seems to be about C language. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that **easily** demonstrate combinatoric growth? It seems like a [variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) should do, on the fact of it.

Comment: @Ron - `const Leg PA29 { PIOA, BIT(29) }; ` is uniform initialization. That's C++.

Comment: well, you could have PN as #define PN(x) P(A, x) P(B, x) P(C, x) P (D, x) and now you have just 32 PN's

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed so. I stand corrected.

Comment: There's boosts preprocessor library which supports loops IIRC.

Comment: Seriously, think about that [mcve]. The way things are now, you posted an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It looks like you need an array. If you don't think so, please explain why in the body of the question.

Comment: You should check if your compiler can optimize actual C function to constant. If it can, just rely on that.

Comment: Or if this really is C++, just use template metaprogramming...

Comment: @hyde - I think template *normal* programming will do. No need to pull out the big guns just yet

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `PIOA` (`B, C, D`) and `BIT(n)` are defined in a way that you can't redefine them to your needs?

Comment: @grek40, yes, cannot.

Comment: But you do have control over the `const Leg P...`? Is the `BIT(n)` macro defined in a way that would allow expansion within a function, using a variable name `n` instead of a numeric constant?

Comment: @grek40, `BIT` is constexpr function. Q is updated.

Comment: @StoryTeller, here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with [Boost preprocessor library](https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor):

```
#include "Pio.hpp"  // Has Leg and BIT definitions
#include "boost/preprocessor.hpp"  //#include "boost/preprocessor/iteration"


/// Alias to shortly produce leg definition
/// The P(A,2) will define PA2 with proper PIO and bit.
#define P(Port,PinN)  \
        const Leg P##Port##PinN { PIO##Port, BIT<unsigned>(PinN) }


#define PA(n)  P(A,n)
#define PB(n)  P(B,n)
#define PC(n)  P(C,n)
#define PD(n)  P(D,n)


#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)   PA(n);
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS     (0, 31)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()  //??=include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()  //-Wtrigraphs

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)   PB(n);
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS     (0, 31)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)   PC(n);
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS     (0, 31)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)   PD(n);
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS     (0, 31)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
```

This works nice. But with on little inconvenience: IDEs will underline `PA5` and others as unresolved symbol.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't post a truly minimal example. So this is a guess at best. But if you are using C++14, and your types are constexpr constructible, then it seems to me you should do away with the preprocessor as much as possible, and just use variable templates:

```
enum port {A, B, C, D};

template<port>
struct PIO_ID;
template<> struct PIO_ID<A>{ static constexpr auto value = PIOA; };
template<> struct PIO_ID<B>{ static constexpr auto value = PIOB; };
template<> struct PIO_ID<C>{ static constexpr auto value = PIOC; };
template<> struct PIO_ID<D>{ static constexpr auto value = PIOD; };

template<port P>
constexpr auto PIO = PIO_ID<P>::value;

template<port PORT, int PIN_NUM>
constexpr Leg P{ PIO<PORT> , BIT(PIN_NUM) };
```

And that's it. Now you can refer to those constants as `P<A, 0>`, and so forth.

Comment: That's *much* nicer than my answer.  (I'll leave my answer up, because it is different, and might be a solution for someone else with a similar problem).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated Q with minimal example.

Comment: My worst problem when I tied to use `constexpr` with vendor's definitions was **reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer**. May be I will define own`PIOx`

Comment: C++ denies to initialize constexpr pointer from integer value. So there is no way.

Answer (score 2):

Do you *really* need `const Leg PA29` (and presumably refer to `PA29` elsewhere)?

If you were prepared to write `PA[29]` and `PA` was of a type that had a suitable `operator []`, then you would just have `PA`, `PB`, `PC`, and `PD` to define (and I probably wouldn't even use a preprocessor define for that).

Alternatively, the [Boost Preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) offers loops.